# Adding image to title of Pivot page and handling touch

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, touch, gesture

I am trying to add image next to pivot control title and I want to be able to touch it. But I can't and I guess it's because pivot is handling touches. This is my code:

```
    <Grid Margin="162,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Tap="MessagesIcon_OnTap">
          <Image Source="/Assets/Images/Icons/messages_icon.png" 
                 x:Name="MessagesIcon"
                 Stretch="Fill" Opacity="1" Width="20" Height="22"
                 Tap="MessagesIcon_OnTap"/>
    </Grid>
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="PlayerPivot" Title="TITLE" >
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Margin="0" x:Name="PlayingPivotItem">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="subtitle" />
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                     ...
```

As you can see I tried catch tap on both (grid which contains image and image it self) but it isn't call. What is the easiest way to get tap gesture on image? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try using this snippet:

```
<controls:Pivot.Title>  
<StackPanel>                   
<TextBlock Text="title" />     
<Image Source="/Images/anyimage.png"/>              
</StackPanel>           
</controls:Pivot.Title>
```

Comment: I don't know that I can change Title for Pivot like this. Now it's working. Thanks